# Where to add this code for a Modal box to work?

Tags: css, html

Hi im using WordPress and was given this code below to add to a website but unsure where I need to add it in order for it work as a Modal or if there is a plugin i can use to add this code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There's three parts to the code: the style, which needs to either go in the header or as a separate style sheet you enqueue; the `<a class="button"` bit which is the actual link you put on the page where you want to open this (I guess this is assuming Bootstrap since there's no script here?); and the modal HTML itself, which can go anywhere on the page e.g. at the bottom as in John's answer. However I'd double check that the iframe here isn't loading before the modal is open - you don't want that to happen on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it is a modal, you should be able to add the code in header.php or footer.php. I would recommened adding to footer.php above wp_footer();